# How to Read Substrings based on Length of the String in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring

I have a String which contains a substrings One of them is "1 . 2 To Other Mobiles" and other is "Total".Now as per my requirement i have to read the Contents between first substring i.e ."1 . 2 To Other Mobiles" and "Total".I am doing it by following code in c#.

```
int startPosition = currentText.IndexOf("1 . 2 To Other Mobiles");
int endPosition = currentText.IndexOf("Total");
string result = currentText.Substring(startPosition, endPosition - startPosition);
```

But the problem that i am facing is "Total" is Many times in my substring..I have to read after the startPosition length to last position length i.e. "Total".
How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to read after the startPosition length **to last position** length

Use [`LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string search1 = "1 . 2 To Other Mobiles";
string search2 = "Total";

int startPosition = currentText.IndexOf(search1);
if(startPosition >= 0)
{
    startPosition += search1.Length;
    int endPosition = currentText.LastIndexOf(search2);
    if (endPosition > startPosition)
    {
        string result = currentText.Substring(startPosition, endPosition - startPosition);
    }
}
```

> What should i do if i need to read for the first "Total" only.

then use [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
// ...
int endPosition = currentText.IndexOf(search2);
if (endPosition > startPosition)
{
    string result = currentText.Substring(startPosition, endPosition - startPosition);
}
```

Comment: Thank u sir for Response.In the given code i am able to get the data till last "Total".What should i do if i need to read for the first "Total" only.

Comment: @Adi: then use `IndexOf`, edited my answer. If you need all positions you need a loop which iterates as long as `IndexOf("Total", lastIndex+1)>=0`.

Comment: if (endPosition > startPosition) This condition is never meeting as "Total" is before also ..

Comment: _"as "Total" is before also .. "_ ?? Why is total before the first substring? I thought that you want to find the substring between both and that "Total" comes after "1 . 2 To Other Mobiles".

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sir i have to Read from "1 . 2 To Other Mobiles" to the immedidate "Total".As "Total" is before as well as after also.So need to read between "1 . 2 To Other Mobiles" and immediate "Total"

Comment: @Adi: i hope that you will find what you're looking for. You should be able to do so with `IndexOf` and `LastIndexOf`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter how to achieve this sir?

Comment: @Adi: i must admit that i'm not sure what string you have and what problems to get the desired substring. It's difficult to help in the comments. You either should edit your question to provide meaningful sample data and more details what's going wrong or ask another question with this specific problem (again with meaningful but short sample data).

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
int startPosition = currentText.IndexOf("1 . 2 To Other Mobiles");
int endPosition = currentText.LastIndexOf("Total") + 5;
string result = currentText.Substring(startPosition, endPosition - startPosition);
```

Comment: @Adi, it is `"Total".Length`. It is added so that the text "Total" itself is also included in the result.

Comment: @CompuChip is right i have entered 5 statically instead of using "Total".Length;

Comment: That's why i prefer to use variables like `toSearch`, then i can change what i want to search without breaking the code. It's also more redable.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [String.LastIndexOf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** you are not adding the length of the first search string `1 . 2 To Other MobilessubstringTotal`

**Solution :**

```
string currentText = "1 . 2 To Other MobilessubstringTotal";
string search1="1 . 2 To Other Mobiles";
string search2="Total";
int startPosition = currentText.IndexOf(search1);
int endPosition = currentText.IndexOf(search2);
string result = currentText.Substring((startPosition+search1.Length), endPosition - (startPosition+search1.Length));
```

**Output:**

result => `substring`

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
string currentText = "1 . 2 To Other Mobiles fkldsjkfkjslfklsdfjk  Total";
string text = "1 . 2 To Other Mobiles";
int startPosition = currentText.IndexOf("1 . 2 To Other Mobiles");
int endPosition = currentText.IndexOf("Total");
string result = currentText.Substring(startPosition + text.Length, endPosition - (startPosition + text.Length));
```

In the text "1 . 2 To Other Mobiles fkldsjkfkjslfklsdfjk  Total";

The output will be:

fkldsjkfkjslfklsdfjk