# How to search for immediate Substring present at multiple places in c#

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring

I have a String which i need to break into multiple substring.Now as per my condition while breaking into substring i have to search for two texts into the string.Here is my two texts..

1. `1 . 2 To Other Mobiles` (This may be changed based on the condition needed in substring)
2. `Total`(This is the last of the substring)

Here is my sample string Content

```
1 . 1 To Airtel Mobile
1 03/MAR/2013 16:06:31 9845070641 05:44 1.80 **
2 04/MAR/2013 10:00:29 9845096416 00:14 0.30 **
Total 25:28 9.30
1 . 2 To Other Mobiles
1 03/MAR/2013 06:41:06 9448485859 00:15 0.40 **
2 04/MAR/2013 18:57:47 9448367847 08:33 3.60 **
3 05/MAR/2013 18:57:05 9448485859 00:42 0.40 **
4 05/MAR/2013 20:13:19 9448367847 00:42 0.40 **
Total 34:33 18.00
1 . 3 To Fixed Landline
21 21/MAR/2013 11:59:35 08066000000 09:34 5.00
22 22/MAR/2013 11:31:33 08066000000 15:20 8.00
Total 01:35:23 54.00
```

Based on the Index of these two texts i am breaking string into substring.Now as per my condition i have to read substrings to the immediate text i.e `Total`.

But in my present code i am reading string to substring till last `Total` text.

Here is my Code:

```
string search1 = "1 . 2 To Other Mobiles";
string search2 = "Total";

int startPosition = currentText.IndexOf(search1);
if (startPosition >= 0)
{
    startPosition += search1.Length;
    int endPosition = currentText.LastIndexOf(search2);
    if (endPosition > startPosition)
    {
        string result = currentText.Substring(startPosition, endPosition - startPosition);
    }
}
```

In Brief i have to search for first searchable text and start reading till the second text.

Comment: what happen with your previous question. http://stackoverflow.com/q/21874852/3184380

Comment: @Nimesh it is reading till last position of text "Total" whereas  i need it to the immediate ones..

Comment: so you dont want to include "Total" in your substring?

Comment: ie. if the string is "1 . 2 To Other Mobiles sdas askdka sdsajhsjdsj dsjdhajdhs Total 2541/-"
then what result should be return?

Comment: @Nimesh yes i dont want to include and want to read till first "Total" only.No need to get the position or index of the last "Total" .Read from "1 . 2 To Other Mobiles" till it gets "Total".

Comment: You have again omitted a short,meaningful sample for `currentText`. It's difficult to understand the problem without sample data.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have added my sample string sir .Now as per my requirement i have to read substring 1 . 2 To Other Mobiles
1 03/MAR/2013 06:41:06 9448485859 00:15 0.40 **
2 04/MAR/2013 18:57:47 9448367847 08:33 3.60 **
3 05/MAR/2013 18:57:05 9448485859 00:42 0.40 **
4 05/MAR/2013 20:13:19 9448367847 00:42 0.40 **

Comment: Change this line 
`int endPosition = currentText.LastIndexOf(search2);` to `int endPosition = currentText.IndexOf(search2);`

Comment: Now you need to edit your question to provide the desired result ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution without Regex done in LinqPad:

```
string source = @"1 . 1 To Airtel Mobile
1 03/MAR/2013 16:06:31 9845070641 05:44 1.80 **
2 04/MAR/2013 10:00:29 9845096416 00:14 0.30 **
Total 25:28 9.30
1 . 2 To Other Mobiles
1 03/MAR/2013 06:41:06 9448485859 00:15 0.40 **
2 04/MAR/2013 18:57:47 9448367847 08:33 3.60 **
3 05/MAR/2013 18:57:05 9448485859 00:42 0.40 **
4 05/MAR/2013 20:13:19 9448367847 00:42 0.40 **
Total 34:33 18.00
1 . 3 To Fixed Landline
21 21/MAR/2013 11:59:35 08066000000 09:34 5.00
22 22/MAR/2013 11:31:33 08066000000 15:20 8.00
Total 01:35:23 54.00";

string search1 = "1 . 2 To Other Mobiles";
string search2 = "Total";

var result = source.Split(new string[] { search1 }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].
                    Split(new string[] { search2 }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0].
                    Dump();
```

Output:

```
1 03/MAR/2013 06:41:06 9448485859 00:15 0.40 **
2 04/MAR/2013 18:57:47 9448367847 08:33 3.60 **
3 05/MAR/2013 18:57:05 9448485859 00:42 0.40 **
4 05/MAR/2013 20:13:19 9448367847 00:42 0.40 **
```

From the comments on your question I presumed you did not want the searchterms to appear in the output, yes?

If you need to repeatidly search the for textblocks with the same start and end parameters, you could wrap this in a method and do let it recursivly start at the split index [1].

Comment: Yes sir ..what is Dump() as it is giving error in my Code..

Comment: Oh sorry. Just ignore `.Dump()`. this is a method native to LinqPad, which throws the current object into the output window. 
Many .Net developers use www.linqpad.net as a scratchpad for code. In short: just remove it. It adds nothing to the functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular expressions to capture the string up until first `search2`

```
var input = "1 . 2 To Other Mobiles asdf asd fas df asd fas dfas df asd fas df sdaf Total asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf another Total ertyertyertyerty eryertwer";

var sub1 = "1 . 2 To Other Mobiles";
var sub2 = "Total";

var match = Regex.Match(input, sub1 + "(.*?)" + sub2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (match.Success)
{
   var m = match.Groups[1].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(sub1 + m);
}
```

This will output

```
1 . 2 To Other Mobiles asdf asd fas df asd fas dfas df asd fas df sdaf
```

If you want up until the last `search2` then remove the `?` in the capture group to make it greedy.

```
var input = "1 . 2 To Other Mobiles asdf asd fas df asd fas dfas df asd fas df sdaf Total asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf another Total ertyertyertyerty eryertwer";

var sub1 = "1 . 2 To Other Mobiles";
var sub2 = "Total";

// note the capture group is missing the ?    
var match = Regex.Match(input, sub1 + "(.*)" + sub2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (match.Success)
{
   var m = match.Groups[1].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(sub1 + m);
}
```

This will output

```
1 . 2 To Other Mobiles asdf asd fas df asd fas dfas df asd fas df sdaf Total asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf another
```